# Installation of RGBDSLAM for not ROS user

Tags: ros, slam, navigation, installation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

When I try to install rgbdslam for my machine using the RGBDSLAM for not ROS users instruction I encountered a problem as follows

when I type ...
$ sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-perception-pcl ros-fuerte-vision-opencv ros-fuerte-octomap-mapping python-rosdep

It gives an error message of ...

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ros-fuerte-perception-pcl
E: Unable to locate package ros-fuerte-vision-opencv
E: Unable to locate package ros-fuerte-octomap-mapping

Some specifications - Ubuntu 12.10, 32 bit

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/66210/installation-of-rgbdslam-for-not-ros-user/) by [eskendertamrat](https://answers.ros.org/users/5193/eskendertamrat/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-06-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Sounds like the previous step hasn't worked out. Maybe you forgot

```
sudo apt-get update
```

So it's probably going to work if you start over.
Otherwise please post the output of

```
cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list
```

---

Originally posted by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) with karma: 6468 on 2013-07-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [boog](https://answers.ros.org/users/5329/boog/) on 2013-07-08**:
Either that or forgot to add the repository from the first instruction, I managed to do it as I'm new to linux